# How to set Save/Cancel pinned at the bottom of activity?

Tags: android

I wonder if there is a simple way of making Save/Cancel buttons in the bottom of the activity like this one:

[Calendar (Add new event) from my LG V10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muvG6.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this....(Tested)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer">

    //put your all views here

        </ScrollView>    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">              
              <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"              
                android:text="Save"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cancelButton1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"                    
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>        
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the Relative layout as your parent layout. Use a linear/ any other layout as your child layout, inside which place your buttons. Add this `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your child layout. Hope this will help

Comment: how about a skeleton sample of XML layout, also don't forget to use ScrollView for the body as the form can be long ;) do this and i will upvote